# sort updated gridview after databind

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Here is the problem part in my code.

```
 DataView view = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
 view.Sort = "user_id ASC, ip_address DESC;

 BalaiStatus.DataSource = view;
 BalaiStatus.DataBind();

 >>BalaiStatus.DataBind().Sort = "ip_address ASC";<<
```

BalaiStatus will handle function BalaiStatus_RowDataBound. This code is to eliminate the same row in the gridview. The codes are:-

```
 string lastRow = "";


 protected void BalaiStatus_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {

     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
         var thisRow = e.Row;

         if (thisRow.Cells[0].Text == lastRow)
         {
             e.Row.Visible = false;
        }
     }
     else {
          DataRowView view = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

          string login = Convert.ToString(view["ip_address"]);
          if (login == "")
          {
              e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = Color.Red;        
          }
          else
          {             
              Global.rowCount = Global.rowCount + 1;

              e.Row.Cells[2].ForeColor = Color.White;
              e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = Color.Green;

          }
          Global.allCount = Global.allCount + 1;
     }
     lastRow = thisRow.Cells[0].Text;
 }
```

So, what I need is, after eliminate the same rows, I want to sort again the updated data in gridview. Please see >>code<<..

Anyone kindly please help me on this problem. Appreciate your opinion or suggestion. Thank Siti.

Answer (score 0):

You should filter the duplicate row before setting the source of the gridview. This will allow you to sort before the binding the grid as well.

This will depend on the source of the dataset *ds*, how are you getting this data?

Rowdatabound should not be used to remove/add rows to the table, that should be done to the the table stores in the dataset *ds*

Comment: thanks for your reply. how to filter before setting the source of the gridview?..any suggestion for function or method to get the row and compare if it is same?

Comment: I think a simple _group_ _by_ query should remove the duplicate rows.
WHat is the source of the dataset, that would help in what type of function can be used.